# write a wav file to audio device using alsa

Tags: wav, alsa

I want to write a .wav file to audio device. I used alsa for that purpose. I took a sample file.Here I am copying the file sample data to buffer.

```
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buff),wave.dataHeader.chunkSize);
    int nframes = wave.dataHeader.chunkSize/2;
    while( nframes > 0 ){
            int r = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, 
                                reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buff), nframes);
            nframes = nframes - r;
            if(r < 0){
                    fprintf (stderr, "write to audio interface failed (%s)\n",
                             snd_strerror (err));
                    exit (1);
            }
            buff += r * 2;
    }
```

My files data is

File Size: 2084
FmtChunk Size: 16
Format Type: 1
Channels: 2
Sample Rate: 48000
Bytes Per Sec: 192000
Bits per sample: 16

here it is giving error
 **a.out: pcm.c:1250: snd_pcm_writei: Assertion `pcm' failed.

Aborted**.
Here what should be the **nframes** value and how should i write to audio device any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you asking about `nframes`, when the error message complains about `playback_handle`?

Comment: the error is in playback_handle only..and also i want to know about *nframes* also